# calculation for different value ranges

Tags: php, numbers

I need help with the next problem...

I have a list of values... prices in my case.

Im converting a csv file with prices. all is very good, but i need a solution to calculate a discount for a range of price.
Ex:

```
1234 , 230
2345, 500
5432 , 800
```

"modified"

i need to apply a discount of 
3% off for values range 100-250
10% off for values range 250-500
25% off for values range 500-1000

so, i have the column with values.

```
$values[2]
$formula = round($values * 0.97, 0); // this is only geting 3% for all values from column.
```

But i need help to get the correct disocunt for a range all ranges.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($values[2] >= 100 && $values[2] <= 250) {
   $discount = 0.97;
}
else if ($values[2] > 250 && $values[2] <= 500) {
   $discount = 0.9;
}
else if ($values[2] > 500 && $values[2] <= 1000) {
   $discount = .75;
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: no you are not missing nothing, just forgot the `;` for `$discount = .75;` 
:D,

Thanks allot